# Почему не работает генератор в Python

Tags: python, циклы

Подскажите почему не работает генератор?
Смысл в том что нужно найти числа содержащие цифру 9. Выдает все что не попадя.
При этом собираю через вложенные циклы, все работает. Ткните носом пожалуйста.

```
res = []
for i in big_list:
   for j in i:
         if '9' in str(j):
             res.append(j)
```

---

```
from pprint import pprint

lst_1 = [i ** 2 for i in range(10) if i % 2]
lst_2 = [i ** 3 for i in range(17) if not i % 2]
lst_3 = [i ** 3 for i in range(10, 15) if i % 2]
lst_4 = [i ** 2 for i in range(10, 18) if not i % 2]
big_list = [lst_1, lst_2, lst_3, lst_4]
pprint(big_list)

res = [num for i in big_list
            for num in i if '9' in str(i)]
print(res)
```

Comment: `if '9' in str(num)` может быть?

Comment: Да, точно. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь ошибка:

```
res = [num for i in big_list
            for num in i if '9' in str(i)]
                                       ^
```

Должно быть

```
res = [num for i in big_list
            for num in i if '9' in str(num)]
```

---

Результат:

> ```
> >>> res
> [9, 49, 4096, 2197, 196]
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

Во вложенном цикле вы правильно применили

```
      if '9' in str(j):
```

но в генераторе, где вы вместо `j` использовали `num`, вы уже не подставили вместо `j` `num`:

```
..... if '9' in str(num)]      # правильно
```

а `i` (неправильно, т.к. `i` - список (в списке `big_list`)).